# Get database info in cart-detailed-product-line.tpl

Tags: php, sql, controller, prestashop, cart

I would need to get database info to be displayed in cart-detailed-product-line.tpl
I need to access the ps_cart table and display infos from a column I created in it. There already is a $cart variable available in this tpl file but it looks like it doesn't get datas from ps_cart. I looked for the php file from where I could call those datas with SQL requests but I don't get to find it...

How can I manage to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find a way by using the displayCartExtraProductActions hook (which is available cart-detailed-product-line.tpl) in my custom module, assign a tpl file and the SQL request to get the data and put this hook where I need in cart-detailed-product-line.tpl.

```php
public function hookDisplayCartExtraProductActions()
    {   
        $result = 'SELECT `my_custom_field`
        FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'cart`
        WHERE `id_cart` = ' . $this->context->cookie->id_cart;

        $templates = Db::getInstance()->getValue($result);

        $this->context->smarty->assign([
            'templates' => unserialize($templates)
        ]);

        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'cart-templates-customs.tpl');
    }
```